# Prove whether the limit of $\dfrac{1}{\ln x}$ as $x$ approaches $1$ exists or not.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

Since the side limits aren't equal, the limit does not exist for the given function.
But I am not allowed to use it, rather it says "you can use well-known fact $\ln x \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow +0$"

My approach:

Let $x_n = e^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$

when $n \rightarrow \infty$ , $x_n \rightarrow 1$

but,

$\dfrac{1}{\ln x_n} = n $ which is divergent as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Thus by the sequential criteria limit does not exist

Comment: I don't immediately see how they expect the $x\to 0$ behavior of $\ln x$ to help you figure out the $x\to 1$ behavior of $\frac1{\ln x}$. It seems like a very strange road to force you down.

Comment: You've shown a special case of $\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{\ln x}=\infty$. You can similarly show $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{1}{\ln x}=-\infty$. Or, in less controversial notation: as $x\to1^\pm$, $\ln x\to0^\pm$ so $\frac{1}{\ln x}\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah. It is not a must. So I haven't used it for the proof

Comment: @J.G. I used the sequential criteria. So, isn't one divergent sequence enough to say the function does not have a limit?

Comment: @Lucifer Some times $\infty$ counts as a limit, some times it does not. It depends on who you ask, and in which context. But if you can show that it approaches $\infty$, and also at the same time approaches $-\infty$, then you can definitely say that there is no limit, as limits, infinite or not, must be unique.

Comment: Well, divergence to $+\infty$ sometimes leads people to say a limit "$=\infty$" rather than "does not exist". If they're using language like that, you can point out behaviour either side of $x$ doesn't even allow _that_ kind of "limit" to exist for $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ as $x\to1$. But I'll leave you to verify what is expected in your course. Edit: @Arthur beat me to it.

Comment: Ah i got it. You mean as an extended real number right? Shall I use a 2nd sequence $x_n = e^{-\dfrac{1}{n}}$ which converges to $1$ but under the function it goes to $-\infty$

Comment: @J.G. will it work?

Comment: @Lucifer Yes, $x_n=e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ would work.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for the reply

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the support

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for the support